# how to add v4 support Library to Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I learning Navigation Drawer Example, but I am adding support library to my project in lib folder.

Here my code. When run on Emulator there is no difference on ListView and Navigation Drawer:

```
// MainActivity 
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private String[] MobilePhones = { "Nokia", "Sumsung", "MicroMax", "Nexus", "Asus" };;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MobilePhones));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Your selected Phone is " + MobilePhones[position],
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `When run on Emulator there is no difference on ListView and Navigation Drawer`. What is that your looking for? There is a sample @ https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html. Also there is library for material drawer on github https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Comment: Naviagation Drawer when the user slide the screen to left side then it show the data. but,here my example it showing normal listview data.

Comment: there is no code where you actually open the drawer. Look at the example in the dev site.